# CAKEPHP: Record not found in table "users" with primary key [NULL]

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

Thanks in advance

pls help as soon as u can

i'm trying to achieve a situation where when a user logs in he is redirected to user view like

localhost/cakephp/users/view/1

where 1 is the user id
in my view method here is what i have

```
public function view($id = null)
{

   $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
       'contain' => []
   ]);

   $this->set('user', $user);
}
```

if i take out the null value in the method argument 
i will get something like this

localhost/cakephp/users/view

whereas i need something like this

localhost/cakephp/users/1

the error i get when the null value is in the view method argument is

Record not found in table "users" with primary key [NULL]

so i fill there is something i'm supposed to add to the view method argument to be able to achieve what i want

Pls help me with how i can achieve this

thanks in anticipation

Comment: I suspect that `$id` is defaulting to `NULL`, and you are querying the db for that value. Add `var_dump($id)` to the top of the function to check the value.

Comment: @JimWright thanks ... It does default to null. How can i fix this thank you

Comment: See the cakephp documentation. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: @JimWright thank you for your prompt and candid response, i have gone thru cakephpcook book on routing as suggested but still kind of not getting it, can you help me with some sample codes for calrifications

thank you.

Comment: @JimWright thank you for your prompt and candid response, i have gone thru cakephpcook book on routing as suggested but still kind of not getting it, can you help me with some sample codes for calrifications

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra check before connecting to DB,

```
public function view($id = null)
{
   if($id){
       $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
           'contain' => []
       ]);

       $this->set('user', $user);
   } else {
       $this->Flash->error('Invalid Request / Invalid User');
   }
}
```

If something else you want to achieve, let me know

Comment: this is what i get when in included the code as suggested 
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/Template\Users\view.ctp, line 20]

and it still ends up echoing the else block while trying to show me the user details

Comment: Because $user is now undefined, you should add a check in your view, to check that $user is empty or not...

Comment: thanks a lot pls how do i implement this check kind of not getting it

thank you

Comment: bilz thanks a lot please how do i implement this check kind of not getting it

thank you

Comment: I have no idea about your view layout, still where you are using "$user->SOME_Property" in your view, just before that add an if condition if($user) then go inside else SHOW them a message.

Answer (score -2):

You can also throw exception for invalid request. This way you don't need to add any check for $user in view.

```
function view($id = null)
{

     if(!$id)
     {
        //Throw exception here
     }

       $user = $this->Users->get($id, [
           'contain' => []
       ]);

       if(!$user)
       {
           //Throw another exception here 
       }

       $this->set('user', $user);

}
```